# NetBeans12 Ant Application: JDK 11: JAX-WS; Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

Tags: ant, java-11, netbeans-12

I am upgrading **javax** to Jakarta jar's to provide support for the latest Java versions. But when I tried to work with SOAP web services in JDK 11 I get a "*...ProviderImpl not found.*" `WebServiceException`.

My Ant project's ***/lib*** contains all the jars below related to Jakarta Soap services:

[image: jars1]

[image: jars2]

I have verified that com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl IS available in also.

But I am still facing the issue below:

```
caughtException = (jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceException) jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

java.lang.NullPointerException
[catch] at jakarta.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.lookupUsingOSGiServiceLoader(FactoryFinder.java:154)
    at jakarta.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:99)
    at jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:64)
    at jakarta.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:82)
    at com.adminserver.remotedebuggerconnector.webservice.remotedebuggerstubs.Services_DebuggerService.<init>(Services_DebuggerService.java:53)
    at com.adminserver.remotedebuggerconnector.RemoteDebugClientWrapper.initializeDebuggerServiceObjects(RemoteDebugClientWrapper.java:51)
    at com.adminserver.remotedebuggerconnector.RemoteDebugClientWrapper.<init>(RemoteDebugClientWrapper.java:35)
    at com.adminserver.asgraphicrulesidemodule.editors.ui.debugger.context.DebuggerContext.createRemoteDebugClientWrapper(DebuggerContext.java:164)
    at com.adminserver.asgraphicrulesidemodule.editors.ui.debugger.context.DebuggerContext.initiateActivityDebuggerService(DebuggerContext.java:115)
    at com.adminserver.asgraphicrulesidemodule.editors.ui.debugeditor.TransactionDebuggerUi.initiateDebuggerService(TransactionDebuggerUi.java:278)
    at com.adminserver.asgraphicrulesidemodule.editors.ui.debugeditor.BaseDebuggerUi$InitiateDebugServiceJob.run(BaseDebuggerUi.java:87)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

I tried below options as per stack forum solution.

In my Ant project the jar shown below exists:

```
<class-path-extension>
                <runtime-relative-path>ext/jaxws-rt-4.0.1.jar</runtime-relative-path>
                <binary-origin>release/modules/ext/jaxws-rt-4.0.1.jar</binary-origin>
            </class-path-extension>
```